# React: Creating a table that uses data from a Http GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I've been struggling a bit with this library and javascript. So here is the deal, I want to build a  table from data I'm collecting from a Http Get request. I'm ok on getting the data,  but I'm not able to work with the Data. It says it is an empty array.

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";

function ServersTable() {
  const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
  const [serverData, setServerData] = useState([]);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const columns = [
    { field: "hostname", headerName: "Hostname", width: 70 },
    { field: "memory", headerName: "Memória", width: 70 },
    { field: "vCpus", headerName: "vCPUs", width: 70 },
    { field: "disk", headerName: "Disco", width: 70 },
    { field: "ip", headerName: "IP", width: 70 },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      await axios
        .get("http://localhost:3333/servers")
        .then((response) => {
          setServerData(response.data);
          fillRows();
          setLoadingData(false);
          
        })
    }
    if (loadingData) {
      getData();
    }
  }, []);

  function fillRows() {
    let rowArray = [];
    for (let count = 0; count < serverData.length; count++) {
      let row;
      row = {
        id: count,
        hostname: serverData[count].hostname,
        memory: serverData[count].configuracao.memoryProvisioned + " GB",
        vCpus: serverData[count].configuracao.cpuProvisioned + " vCPUs",
        disk: serverData[count].configuracao.totalDiskGB + " GB",
        ip: serverData[count].ip,
      };
      rowArray.push(row);
    }
    setRows(rowArray);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {loadingData ? (
        <p>Loading Please Wait...</p>
      ) : (
        <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} checkboxSelection />
      )}
      {console.log("Server Data:")}
      {console.log(serverData)}
      {console.log("Rows:")}
      {console.log(rows)}
    </>
  );
}

export default ServersTable;
```

I think I'm struggling in understandig how the async is working and I'm trying to access the data before it is ready. Though I tried everything to make it work and wait for the data to be ready.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you put a `console.log(serverData)` before `return` inside the functional component to find out what's coming as `serverData` ? Please put that in your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, `setState` hook does not Update the synchronously. this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783011/9133304) for more information.

So, this statement:

```
setServerData(response.data);
```

not immediately change your `serverData` , therefore in your `fillRows()`  function  `serverData` is considered an empty array since you defined it as an empty array in the `setState` initializer.

(since there are many solutions to solve this problem) You can pass `response.data` to `fillRows` function (instead of using getting `serverData` from the state ) like  `fillRows(response.data)`.

So, change your `fillRows` function to

```
function fillRows(responseData) {
    let rowArray = [];
    for (let count = 0; count < responseData.length; count++) {
      let row;
      row = {
        id: count,
        hostname: responseData[count].hostname,
        memory: responseData[count].configuracao.memoryProvisioned + " GB",
        vCpus: responseData[count].configuracao.cpuProvisioned + " vCPUs",
        disk: responseData[count].configuracao.totalDiskGB + " GB",
        ip: responseData[count].ip,
      };
      rowArray.push(row);
    }
    setRows(rowArray);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to async nature of setState. Using Callback can help in your case.
I just edited your getData function.

```
async function getData() {
   await axios
     .get("http://localhost:3333/servers")
     .then((response) => {
        setServerData(response.data, () => {
          fillRows();
          setLoadingData(false);
        }); 
   })
}
```